# How to show that the following subsets of V are vector or affine subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, affine-geometry

Consider the vector space V of polynomials with real coefficients of degree less than or equal to 2. Say, justifying the answer, if the following subsets of V are vector or affine subspaces.

$(i)$ The subset $U ⊂ V$ of the polynomials divisible by $x - 1$ 
$(ii)$ The subset $L ⊂ V$ of polynomials with a known term equal to 2018.

For $(i)$ we know since $f(x)=x-1$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients then given the following generic polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, $U$ will be all the polynomials $q(x)$ such us $p(x)=f(x)q(x)$. From here, I believe I should verify its a subspace by checking its closed under addition and scalar multiplication and that zero belongs to $U$

For $(ii)$ I'm not sure how to show that its an affine subspace, neither I understand well the differences comparing with the subspaces. I'll be very thankful if someone can clarify this conceptually and help me with what I should do.

Comment: What do you mean by "with a known term equal to $2018$"? That *some* coefficent is $2018$, depending on the polynomial? That *all* polynomials of $L$ have the value $2018$ in the *same* degree?

Comment: I'm certainly not sure, is defined like that. I believe that given any term of a generic polynomial one of them is know to be 2018, not necessarily only the terms with. the unknowns.

Comment: I think it means that a specific term has coefficient $2018$.  That is, we have all quadratic polynomials with constant term $2018$, or all quadratic polynomials with linear term $2018x$ or all quadratic polynomials with quadratic term $2018x^2$.

Comment: If the term equaling $2018$ varies, there's not much to say: for example $2018+x$ and $2018+2018x$ satisfy this condition, but their sum $2019+2019x$ does not, so $L$ won't be an affine space let alone a subspace.